# How do I make a dynamically named $scope variable?

Tags: angularjs

I have several (over 30) feeder lists which the console.log has several nodes looking like this:

```
{
   [functions]: ,
   __metadata: { },
   ID: 8,
   Id: 8,
   Title: "SharePoint"
}
```

So I want to display the **name** (which in SharePoint that is called **Title**) of **ANY OF THE LISTS** rather than the ID by modifying this function to accept a **list** parameter and dynamically create a **$scope."list"[w]** variable. It would save me having to duplicate 30 functions that look like this:

```
$scope.getWebsite = function(id){
    for(w=0; w<$scope.websites.length; w++){
        if($scope.websites[w].ID == id){
        return $scope.websites[w].Title;
        } // end if
    } // end for
};
```

and call it like this:

```
<p>{{getValue('division', thisProject[0].Division_ID)}}</p>
```

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
$scope.getValue = function( list, id ){
    var dyno = '$scope.' + list;
    for(w=0; w<dyno.length; w++){
            if(dyno[w].ID == id){
            return dyno[w].Title;
            } // end if
        } // end for
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of concatenating `'$scope.' + list`, try this:

```
var dyno = $scope[list];
```

Your function would look like this:

```
$scope.getValue = function( list, id ){
    var dyno = $scope[list];
    for(w=0; w<dyno.length; w++){
      if(dyno[w].ID == id){
          return dyno[w].Title;
      } // end if
    } // end for
};
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r6i7RWOLJD5L6zgbnaHx?p=preview)